# Phpunit reusable test methods in symfony

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony4

Let's assume that I have three entites: `UserEntity`, `ZooEntity` and `AnimalEntity`. In order to create zoo I have to create user, because zoo has to have owner. In order to create animal I have to create zoo.

Going further I have 3 controllers for each entity. I also have 3 test classes for controller testing.

- `UserControllerTest`
- `ZooControllerTest`
- `AnimalControllerTest`

In animal test, every time, in each test (to make every test independent) I have to create user and then zoo. Therefore I created traits eg: `UserTestTrait` and `ZooTestTrait` which have `createUser` and `createZoo(user)` methods.

1. I was wondering about chaning those traits into services. But then where I should keep them?
   Would be `tests/services/ZooService` a good place?

For now I such structure:

- `tests/Controller/Rest/ZooControllerTest`
- `tests/Controller/Rest/traits/ZooTestTrait`

2. Assuming that I have those services and every service should have access to eg. entity manager, how can I access that in service? eg. `ZooService` located in `tests/services/ZooService`
3. How can I use that service in controller? Lets assume that I would like to have it in setUp method:

   ```
    protected function setUp(): void {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();

        // access the zoo service, that has access to the entity manager
    }
   ```

Comment: Why do you want to write a service for this? Why not simply use a common parent class and extend your testcases from that?

Comment: Additionally, a service should never have accesss to the container. Inject the services you need into the service, avoid to inject the container itself

Comment: @NicoHaase how in PHP you want to extend two classes in AnimalControllerTest? I know that ZooTest could inherit User, but in more complex case it would not be as easy as in example I provided. Going further, having one "Common" parent class, would not be good, because of different things that it does - eg. create user, create zoo. It should be placed in different classes.

Comment: @NicoHaase yea I know about it, it was just example, I will change it into entity manager :)

Comment: you're overthinking it. symfony by default has the WebTestCase, just write your own MyWebTestCase that extends WebTestCase, give it functions à la createZoo(), createAnimal(?Zoo) etc. you obviously don't let ZooControllerTest extend UserControllerTest, that would be silly. ZooControllerTest then extends MyWebTestCase.

Comment: @Jakumi in my opinion putting all different methods to MyWebTestCase is silly. It also breaks S rule in SOLID. I think that tests also should be written with good manners and not putting everything into one class...

Comment: it breaks S? how? test helper methods that apparently are used by all of your controllers belong in the common class they extend, which is semantically exactly the place they belong. and how the f is that different from putting it all into a service? and you're right, you shouldn't put "everything" into one class, just the helper methods that are used by (almost) all controller tests. And sometimes you have to bend the rules slightly. SOLID isn't *law*, it's a set of rules to be applied in a sensible manner. making it worse just to follow the rules is not their intention.

Comment: Yea, you're right about that my traits also break that rule. So finally there's not good way of doing it when talking about tests :)

Comment: there is. it's called KISS. a common parent class is **simple**, doesn't really *break* SOLID, bends a little perhaps, but it's all better than multiple traits that assume other traits have been defined and stuff or injecting a service which only purpose is to hold a collection of functions, to which you always have to give parameters, that are already defined in the webtestcase/parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself a better approach. Using DoctrineFixturesBundle is a very satisfying way of providing test data. It's even better, when you integrate the Fixtures into your Tests - which might slow them down, but the quality gain is super convenient.
[see this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ger86/symfony-improving-your-tests-with-doctrinefixturesbundle-1a37b704ac05)
My AbstractControllerTest Class looks similar to this:

```
<?php


namespace App\Tests\Functional\Controller;

use App\DataFixtures\AbstractAppFixtures;
use App\DataFixtures\UserFixtures;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataFixtures\ContainerAwareLoader;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Cookie;

abstract class AbstractControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
/**
 * @var ORMExecutor
 */
private $fixtureExecutor;

/**
 * @var ContainerAwareLoader
 */
private $fixtureLoader;

/**
 * set up before test
 */
public function setUp(): void {
    $kernel = static::getKernelClass();

    static::$kernel = new $kernel('dev', true);
    static::$kernel->boot();
    static::$container = static::$kernel->getContainer();
    $this->addFixture(new UserFixtures());
}

/**
 * @param AbstractAppFixtures $fixture
 */
protected function addFixture(AbstractAppFixtures $fixture) {
    $add = true;
    $activeFixtures = $this->getFixtureLoader()->getFixtures();
    foreach ($activeFixtures as $activeFixture) {
        if (get_class($activeFixture) === get_class($fixture)) {
            $add = false;
        }
    }
    if ($add) {
        $this->getFixtureLoader()->addFixture($fixture);
        if ($fixture instanceof DependentFixtureInterface) {
            /** @var AbstractAppFixtures $parentFixture */
            foreach ($fixture->getDependencies() as $parentFixture) {
                if (class_exists($parentFixture)) {
                    $this->addFixture(new $parentFixture());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 *
 */
protected function executeFixtures() {
    $this->getFixtureExecutor()->execute($this->getFixtureLoader()->getFixtures());
}

protected function getContainer() {
    if (static::$container) {
        return static::$container;
    }
    return static::$kernel->getContainer();
}

/**
 * @return ORMExecutor
 */
private function getFixtureExecutor() {
    if (!$this->fixtureExecutor) {
        $em = $this->getEm();
        $this->fixtureExecutor = new ORMExecutor($em, new ORMPurger($em));
    }
    return $this->fixtureExecutor;
}

/**
 * @return ContainerAwareLoader
 */
private function getFixtureLoader() {
    if (!$this->fixtureLoader) {
        $this->fixtureLoader = new ContainerAwareLoader($this->getContainer());
    }
    return $this->fixtureLoader;
}
}
```

Comment: It's not connected with my question.

Comment: Well, it gives you the opportunity to make all tests independent from e.o.
Sorry, if it's not what you were asking for.

Comment: Loading fixtures WITHIN a test looks strange to me. Why not perform all the fixture setup **before** starting the tests?

Comment: @NicoHaase in my case I also have fixtures that are loaded before tests. I agree with you.

Comment: With the method above you can load specific fixtures through the setUp() method. This enables you to only load the fixtures needed for that specific test. The advantage I found for myself is, that in any test method you can safely assume that the database content is exactly as in the fixture's definitions. I personally don't like that tests can manipulate the state of my database which can then interfere with other tests (when not carefully implemented).

Comment: @L.Gerhardt have a look at https://packagist.org/packages/dama/doctrine-test-bundle if you want to avoid changing data

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you, I'll definitely look into it!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to consider is to introduce [test data builder](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html). Just because you have that dependency of `Animal` -> `Zoo` -> `Owner` doesn't mean that you have to deal with it in your tests. Of course, without having seen your tests, it's hard to tell. But I assume that, when testing the `AnimalController`, it is important that a valid `Animal` exists, not so much in which exact zoo with which exact owner. But even if that's the case, you could make your test data builders do the work for you.

The data builders don't deal with persistence, though. But this is a good thing, since you could use them for both, unit and functional tests.

I usually split up my `test` folder usually into `Unit`, `Integration`, `Functional` and `Support`. `Support` being support code for the tests. Regarding your question where to put the service, this would also be in `Support`. That being said, you probably won't even need the service you have thought of. The data builder create the entities you need in your tests, so you just have to persist it.